# Registry Edit using .Net code Access Issue

Tags: c#, registry

We are trying to access a remote registry from one virtual machine to another via IIS using .NET code.

When attempting to run the code, we end up getting an `UnauthorizedAccessException`.

Any thoughts for a fix for this issue?

**Code:**

```
RegistryKey key = RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, "USTR-ERl2-0899.na.uis.xxxxx.com");

if (key != null) { key = key.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\xyxz\"); }
```

Comment: You really should post some code.  It will make determining what's going on a lot easier.

Comment: In addition to what @Froopy mentioned, your question needs more detail. What level of permission do you have on both systems? How is it being accessed via IIS? What protocol is being used between the VMs (WinRM, named pipes, COM, etc)?

Comment: @Froopy , Hi I am  using the below code  //  RegistryKey key = RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, "USTR-ERl2-0899.na.uis.xxxxx.com");
            //if (key != null)
            //{
            //    key = key.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\xyxz\");
        }

Comment: IIS accesss via App pool [Tries Network service,local srevice,local system,custom account] , protocl is WinRM ..

Comment: Is the Remote Registry service turned on at either of the virtual machines?

Comment: @AbrahamMathewAjoy ensure you are running as an administrator.